# How do I make my parent component re-run an api call on page refresh using React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app that loads a list of movies from my API. When the user clicks a movie, it uses react router to send them to a path with the movie ID in, and the Router renders the player Components, which looks up the movie id in the movies API repsonse which is passed to it as a prop and they can watch it. This works ok.

My question is that when the page is reloaded, the components don't have access to the data from the inital API call anymore and nothing works. Why is that API call not being re-run when the page is reloaded?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function Player({ movies }) {
  let { tmdb_id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {tmdb_id}</h3>
      <div id='playerContainer'>
        movie title: {movies ? movies.find((x) => { return x.tmdb_id === tmdb_id}).name : "movie"}
        <ReactPlayer url={movies ? movies.find((x) => { return x.tmdb_id === tmdb_id}).video : ""} playing={false} controls width='100%' height='100%' />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}


function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/allmovies')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setMovies(data);
      })
      .catch(console.log)
    }, [movies]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          hello
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/watch/:tmdb_id">
              <Player movies={movies} />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <ul id="movieList">
            {movies.map((item,i) => 
              <li><Link key={i} to={"/watch/"+ item.tmdb_id} >{item.name}</Link></li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not re-run api call is because it is out of the scope. 
The approach should be in using useParams and access the params from URL instead instead. Thus making the API call in the child component after accessing the param from URL.

Like

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

// Params are placeholders in the URL that begin
// with a colon, like the `:id` param defined in
// the route in this example. A similar convention
// is used for matching dynamic segments in other
// popular web frameworks like Rails and Express.

export default function ParamsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h2>Accounts</h2>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}


function Child() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

From the above you can see that the URL param is accessed in the Child component.

Comment: I understand. The reason I didn't take this approach is because the API call needs to be run in the parent component to load the list of movies, and to run it a second time in the child component seemed wasteful when I could just push the full list of movies down as a prop and use the URL Param to lookup the movie in that movie array. But you think I should do an API call in both the parent component and the child?

Comment: In this case, you probably just use an if/else statement to retrieve the list if the movie is undefined in props.